# Qt Quick with same style of QtWidgets

Tags: python, qtquick2, pyside2, qtwidgets

I have a project with QML and Python with some style:

`styles = ['Default', 'Universal', 'Fusion', 'Material', 'Imagine']`

which I set in this way:

```
qt_args = [sys.argv[0], '-style', styles[2] + sys.argv[1:]
app = QGuiApplication(qt_args)
```

None of them is equal to the default style of QtWidgets. Can I have the same style of QtWidgets in QtQuick?

[image: Left: QtWidgets in Qt Design - Right: Fusion style in Python-QML app]

Left: QtWidgets in Qt Design

Right: Fusion style in Python-QML app

Comment: Fusion should work. Please provide a [mre] and show images

Comment: Ok, I made an update with images.

Comment: It seems that this is another style and I do not think it is present in QML

Comment: It looks like the "windows" style: https://www.qt.io/blog/desktop-styling-with-qt-quick-controls that is introduced in Qt6 (pyside6) that is not available in PySide2

Comment: Ok, I tried it works (there is some difference e.g. the button change color with hover  in qtWidgetand the font is more weight in Pyside6) but now with Pyside6 (before I had Pyside2) I have this error: module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed. I used DropShadow. Can I have GraphicalEffects in PySide6. My import is "import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0"

Comment: QtGraphicalEffects was removed in Qt 6.0 (other modules as well) but will be reinstated in Qt 6.1 so you'll have to wait.